# using JavaScript to Store Countdown timer into a cookie without restarting timer after a page refresh or closed

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I am developing an examination web application and I am using JavaScript to perform a countdown and to store the time into the cookie so that when the page is refreshed or purposely closed, it doesn't restart the countdown from the beginning over and over.

My observation is that it stores  the cookie and retrieves it from the last timing then immediately starts from the beginning again.

**My JavaScript Code below**

```
<script>
var  loginUser = "<?php echo $uid ?>";
// Defining the set Cookie method
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
// Defining get cookie function
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

// Return or Get the time stored in the cookie if available
   var oldTime = parseInt(getCookie(loginUser), 10);

// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date().getTime() + ((4/180)*60*60*1000);

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

     // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    //
    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    var oldTime = parseInt(getCookie(loginUser), 10);
        setCookie(loginUser, distance, 30);

     if( isNaN(oldTime))
     {
         alert("new user NaN");
      // Find the distance between now an the count down date

        // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
     }
     else{


        // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds from the saved distance
        // in the cookie
        var days = Math.floor(oldTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((oldTime % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((oldTime % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((oldTime % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
     }





    //Output the result in an element with id="timer"
  document.getElementById("timer").value = hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    //var n = oldTime.toString();
    //document.getElementById("timer").value = n;


    // If the count down remains 15 minutes, write some text

if (minutes == 1 && seconds == 1) {
        alert("Hello! 1 minute gone");
    }


    // If the count down is over, write some text
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("timer");
        timer.value= "EXPIRED";
        alert("Hello! Exam is over");
        location = "http://localhost:81/aquaexam/exam_complete.php?id=1";
    }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

**My HTML Code**

```
<tr width="100%" style="text-align:right; align:right;"> <td >  <input type="text" name="timer" id="timer" size="20" readonly="true" style="text-align:center;"/></td></tr>
```

Comment: Why don't you use localstorage ?

Comment: Okay but I have not used the Local storage Technology before. I am studying it right away. I also think the problem is because I didn't specify expiration at the point of call of the set-cookie method.

Comment: Just easy.
localstorage.setItem("counter", 1000);
var counter  = localstorage.getItem("counter");

Comment: Thanks for the support. I figured it out using cookie and I am still trying to implement localstorage. Regards

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solved it.

**Final JavaScript Code.** **You can just copy and paste for use.**

```
<script>
// define variable for cookie name using the user login id
var  loginUser = "<?php echo $uid ?>";
// Defining the set Cookie method
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
// Defining get cookie function
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

// Function that will call when document loaded.
window.onload = function () {
// Return or Get the time stored in the cookie if available
   var oldTime = parseInt(getCookie(loginUser), 10);

   if(isNaN(oldTime) == false)
    {
            // Reset the date or time we're counting down to by
          //adding the Cookie time to the present for continous countdown
          var countDownDate = new Date().getTime() + oldTime;

         // Update the count down every 1 second    
        var x = setInterval(function() {
        // Get todays date and time
        var now = new Date().getTime();
            // Find the distance between now an the count down date
        var distance = countDownDate - now;
        setCookie(loginUser, distance, 30);
        // Update the count down every 1 second

        // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds from the saved distance
        // in the cookie
        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);


         //Output the result in an element with id="timer"
  document.getElementById("timer").value = hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

            // If the count down remains 15 minutes,  notification alert
    if (minutes == 15 && seconds == 1) {
        alert("Hello! 15 minutes to go" );
    }

    // If the count down remains 5 minutes,  notification alert
    if (minutes == 5 && seconds == 1) {
        alert("Hello! 5 minutes to go" );
    }

// If the count down is over, notification alert and automatically submits the exam
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("timer");
        timer.value= "EXPIRED";
        alert("Hello! Exam is over");
        location = "http://localhost:81/aquaexam/exam_complete.php?id=1";
    }

        }, 1000);
     }
     else{

     // Set the date or time we're counting down to
    var countDownDate = new Date().getTime() + ((1)*60*60*1000);

           // Update the count down every 1 second
               var x = setInterval(function() {
             // Get todays date and time
               var now = new Date().getTime();
           // Find the distance between now an the count down date
               var distance = countDownDate - now;

               setCookie(loginUser, distance, 30);


      // Find the distance between now an the count down date

        // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    //Output the result in an element with id="timer"
  document.getElementById("timer").value = hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";


        // If the count down remains 15 minutes,  notification alert
    if (minutes == 15 && seconds == 1) {
        alert("Hello! 15 minutes to go" );
    }

    // If the count down remains 5 minutes,  notification alert
    if (minutes == 5 && seconds == 1) {
        alert("Hello! 5 minutes to go" );
    }

// If the count down is over, notification alert and automatically submits the exam
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("timer");
        timer.value= "EXPIRED";
        alert("Hello! Exam is over");
        location = "http://localhost:81/aquaexam/exam_complete.php?id=1";
    }
}, 1000);
   }
}
```

**My HTML Code**

```
<tr width="100%" style="text-align:right; align:right;"> <td >  <input type="text" name="timer" id="timer" size="20" readonly="true" style="text-align:center;"/></td></tr>
```